# Canvas animation with requestAnimationFrame()

Tags: javascript

I'm in the first steps of developing a game. I draw a canon which should move right in the canvas. This is my code:

```
            window.addEventListener('load', function(){
                var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
                var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
                var x = 185;
                var y = 320;
                var W = 30;
                function drawCanon(x, y, W){
                    //CANON
                    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
                    ctx.moveTo(x, y);
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.lineTo(x + W/5 * 3, y);
                    ctx.lineTo(x + W/5 * 4, y + W * 2);
                    ctx.lineTo(x - W/5, y + W * 2);
                    ctx.lineTo(x, y);
                    ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.fill();
                    ctx.arc(x + W/10 * 3, y + 2 * W, W/2, 0, Math.PI);
                    ctx.fill();
                    //ROUES
                    ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(156, 92, 23)";
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(x - W/50 * 12, y + W/50 * 102, W/5 * 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
                    ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.fill();
                    ctx.beginPath();
                    ctx.arc(x + W/50 * 42, y + W/50 * 102, W/5 * 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
                    ctx.closePath();
                    ctx.fill();
                }
                function draw(x, y, W){
                    drawCanon(x, y, W);
                    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
                    x++;
                    window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){draw(x, y, W)}, 30);
                }
                draw(x, y, W);
            });
```

Nothing appears on the canvas, the drawCanon() and the clearRect work correctly but not the last line: window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){draw(x, y, W)});

Could anybody help me?

Comment: I doubt it's the problem, but it could be: Your code is passing **two** arguments to `requestAnimationFrame`. It only accepts one. It could well be that the `requestAnimationFrame` implementation you're trying to run this with expressly disallows extra arguments (as a means of reserving them for later). Chrome's doesn't, though (it just ignores them).

Comment: Also note that you're calling draw on **every** animation frame. That's typically about 60/second. You're increasing `x` by 1 on each of those. So that's going to shoot off the page in just under seven seconds...

Comment: use `requestAnimationFrame(draw)`  with no function argument, anywhere, those are local values

Comment: I tryed this:
window.requestAnimationFrame(function(){draw(x, y, W)});
i tryed with only draw as argument but without its specific argument I don't see how it would be able to draw the canon at the right place... 
I really don't know what to do, is there another way to make animations work?

Answer (score 0):

The `.requestAnimationFrame` only accepts one argument. 
Also, when possible, avoid using anonymous functions, and as a good pratice, limit the FPS of the animation in your function (execute it only when a certain amount of time has passed).

```js
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
var x = 15;
var y = 10;
var W = 30;
var fps=1/60

const drawCannon = (x, y, W) => {
  //CANON
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(0, 0, 0)";
  ctx.moveTo(x, y);
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineTo(x + W/5 * 3, y);
  ctx.lineTo(x + W/5 * 4, y + W * 2);
  ctx.lineTo(x - W/5, y + W * 2);
  ctx.lineTo(x, y);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.arc(x + W/10 * 3, y + 2 * W, W/2, 0, Math.PI);
  ctx.fill();
  //ROUES
  ctx.fillStyle = "rgb(156, 92, 23)";
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x - W/50 * 12, y + W/50 * 102, W/5 * 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill();
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x + W/50 * 42, y + W/50 * 102, W/5 * 2, 0, Math.PI * 2);
  ctx.closePath();
  ctx.fill(); 
}

let then = 0

let animation = () => {

  let now = new Date().getTime();
  let elapsedTime = (now - then) / 1000
  
  if ( elapsedTime > fps) {
    ctx.clearRect(0, 0, 400, 400);
    x++;
    drawCannon(x, y, W)
    then = new Date().getTime();
  }
     

  window.requestAnimationFrame(animation);
}

window.requestAnimationFrame(animation);
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```